# How to Add Note/field to each order product in woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

does anyone have an idea how to add an editable field to each ordered product?

I would like to add information, visible to the customer and administrator, for each product ordered, not the entire order. (This feature is also needed)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

if you can display note filed in your cart to particular product so you can try these.

```
function custom_note_cart_item( $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
  $notes = isset( $cart_item['notes'] ) ? $cart_item['notes'] : '';
  printf(
  '<div><textarea class="%s" id="cart_notes_%s" data-cart-id="%s">%s</textarea></div>',
  'prefix-cart-notes',
   $cart_item_key,
   $cart_item_key,
   $notes
  );
 }
 add_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart_item_name', 'custom_note_cart_item', 10, 2 );
```

[image]